# using parent dot notation in xpath to find another branch in the XML tree

Tags: xpath, notation

I'm running an xslt on an XML that at one point puts my current node at the following "item" element in the tree:

```
host/device/item
```

I've found through experimentation that the following xpath takes the xslt back up to the "host" branch of the XML tree, then successfully locates the "trigger" grand child element of the "host" element.

```
../.././setting/trigger
```

It works, but the xpath syntax seems odd to me. The dot parent notation `../../.` makes sense when you read it from the `.` from right to left. But the child phrase notation `setting/trigger` only make sense if you read from left to right. The "final meaning" of the entire xpath is equivalent to saying:

```
host/setting/trigger
```

Is it always true that the middle `../.` section of the xpath (or however many parent `../` levels it is) is always ignored to create the final meaning `host/device/trigger`?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean when you say that part of the expression makes sense RtoL and the other makes sense LtoR.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: That middle `/.` is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks, Alejandro. I just tried "../../setting/trigger" and it worked just as well as "../.././setting/trigger"

Answer (score 4):

Since `.` means self, you could interpret it as being ignored.  `./././././././*` means the same as `./*`, which means the same as `*`.

Regarding Reading the XPath, breaking it down from the context node `host/device/item`

In `../.././setting/trigger`, the `/` characters separate the node tests, so, LtoR:

`..` you are now at host/device,

`..` you are now at host

`.` you are still at host

`setting` you are now at host/setting

`trigger` you are now at host/setting/trigger

If you read it RtoL, then you must understand that instead of following node-tests, you are reading each node test with the opposite meaning, and your context is where you want to end up, so:

from `host/setting/trigger` (your desired endpoint)

`trigger` (read as `..`), you are now at `host/setting`

`setting` (again, `..`), you are now at host

`.` (`.`), you are still at host

`..` (read as `*`) you *might* now be at host/device

`..` (read as `*`) you *might* now be at host/device/item

Comment: Thanks, Paul. The best I've come up with to get my head around the "walk up the tree" and then the "walk down the sibling branch" is divide the xpath into three "phrases":
"../../." is the grandparent of the current node
"setting" is the child of the grandparent
"trigger" is the grandchild of the grandparent
I just have to remind myself that everything to the left of the "." is a leap up the tree first, before the child elements are examined.

Comment: Just read each individual node test, i.e. 5 phrases.  `..` means parent, `.` means self, and the identifiers in your example are child elements.  `*/*/./setting/trigger`, for example, involves no leaping up the tree.

Comment: what does `/army/battalion/squad.0` mean? does that mean the first element of `army` object?